# Are there any limitations/regulations to be followed while wallet-wallet transfering?

Tags: transactions, wallet-transfer

Technical limitations similar to the ones which developers need to respect while crawling sites?

And can automated scripts be written with the limitations in mind?  What are the possible bottlenecks for such operations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about external regulations and jurisdictions that will vary depending on where a user is located

Comment: I'm reviewing this question - can you say more what you mean by "regulation"? Are you talking about legal or technical regulations?

Comment: @paulmorriss I am asking about technical regulations. Edited the question accordingly :)

Comment: I don't understand the edited question in regard to technical limitations. Are there some documented cases or concerns about wallet-to-wallet transfers and if so, can you link them?

Comment: Are you worried about being scammed, hacked, or keylogged?

Comment: @high110 No, I'm asking whether they are limitations set for such transactions, like the min time between two operations, etc!

Comment: What is the difference with a wallet-wallet transfer and a standard transfer?  "Technical regulations" as a phrase also isn't clear and it's still in the title...

Comment: @eth Consider scraping from a site: Some have regulations like _you should give atleast a time gap of 6s before making a call_.  You can violate them however, but you'd put your acc into danger.  So, such type pof tech. regulations :)

Answer (score 2):

I recently found this one out, but there is no checksum - so enter carefully or use a namereg according to Vitalik:

> You're not meant to use ether addresses; you're meant to use the namereg and equivalents of things like bip70.

Taylor also mentioned it may be added into a version of Ethereum post homestead.

> I think everyone wants checksums and understands the benefits, but delivering a stable network protocol upgrade is of chief importance right now and has been since the beginning. Additional functionality in the clients themselves will hopefully follow soon after the Homestead hard-fork. :)

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/33l08f/do_ethereum_address_not_have_a_checksum_like/

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/425js8/maybe_we_should_reconsider_checksums_as_default/